# Откуда импортируется модуль django?

Tags: python, django

Начал изучать django, и в туториалах по нему люди пишут такое:

```python
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Не могу понять откуда взялся модуль django, ведь в папке django-проекта файла "django.py" нет?

Comment: Наводящий вопрос: Вы не задумывались, откуда берётся, например, модуль `os`, когда делаете `import os` или `time`? Логично предположить, что есть какое-то общее место, откуда всё это импортируется, а возможно и не одно. И имя этим местам PYTHONPATH вроде бы. А ещё *Начал изучать... в туториалах пишут*. Просто рукалицо. Я понимаю, что книги не в моде, но хоть пару десятков страниц про самые основы можно было осилить?

Comment: Когда вы вызываете установку модулей (например через `pip install`), то они попадают в папку интерпретатора. А при импорте интепретатор ищет в той папке запрашиваемый модуль. Кроме основ джанго, нужно и про основы питона читать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во время импорта модуля Python сначала ищет его в папке "около себя", т.е. в той же, где запускается скрипт, здесь Вы правы.

А вот если рядом модуля нет, происходит следующее: Python начинает искать модуль в специальном списке папок с модулями. Получить данный список можно так:

```python
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Он проходит по каждой папке в поисках нужного модуля.

При установке через pip, как уже отметили в комментарии, нужная папка автоматически добавляется в этот список. Также изначально, сразу после установки Python, в этом списке хранятся папки, содержащие стандартные модули, наподобие `os`, `sys` и `time`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: @СергейРазумов Если ответ Вас устроил, проголосуйте за него. Наиболее полезный – примите (зелёной галкой).

Answer (score 1):

django обычно лежит в `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django` или для виндовс в `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38\Lib\site-packages\django` или `C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\django`

Посмотреть список папок, где могут быть установленны модули можно функцией в питон

```
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

Comment: Или в виртуальном окружении или вообще где угодно, если туда указывает .`sys.path`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 1):

При импорте модуля интерпретатор сначала ищёт встроенный модуль с таким именем. Если такого модуля нет, то идёт поиск файла в списке директорий, определённых в переменной sys.path.
Если в директории нет django.py поиск пойдет по папке lib, где и будет найден.
Более подробно можно ознакомиться с процессом в документации к import

Comment: Спасибо, понял.